# "Uncaught ReferenceError: createDayLabel is not defined" - How do I resolve this error to get Materialize's date picker to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, materialize

I'm using Webpack in combination with React and the Materialize UI framework. I added the Materialize [date picker](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) according to the instructions, but when I load the page, the date picker doesn't work and I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createDayLabel is not defined
```

I've forced use of jQuery version 2.1.4 to resolve a conflict with sizzler, though using the most current version of jQuery doesn't resolve the problem either.

Any other ideas on how to address this error?

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to use the webpack.ProvidePlugin in webpack.config.js to point the functions at issue to jQuery:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "Hammer": "hammerjs/hammer",
        createDayLabel: "jquery",
        createWeekdayLabel: "jquery"
    })
  ]
```

Then, reload Webpack and you're good to go.